# Pivot Table: Divide one value by another

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I am in search of how I can divide the value of one field by the value of another field. I have been googling for hours but cannot seem to find a solution. I have explored "Fields, Items, & Sets" but it does not appear to be able to do what I desire (or I just don't understand it well enough to create a solution).

Simply put, within the Pivot Table below, I want to divide the "Average (MB/s)" by "St. Dev. (MB/s)" (e.g. in B8, B6/B7; in C8, C6/C7; etc). Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Pivot Table]

Comment: Pivot tables do their work at the raw data level.  If you want calculations using the results, add your own external columns with formulas referencing the pivot table cells.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid this was the case but wanted to ask the community in case it was an issue of me simply lacking needed knowledge on the subject.